# CGI/Perl "use" function

Tags: perl, cgi

```
use API;
use Database;
use Routines;
use Encode qw/encode decode/;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp;
use File::Basename;
```

1. how can i know where those module come from?
2. what kind of doc should i download to see implementation of those function inside these modules?

Thank you in advance, guys. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`perldoc -m`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html) to see the package's content:

```
$ perldoc -m CGI
package CGI;
require 5.004;
use Carp 'croak';
...
```

Or the `-l` switch to see where the package is:

```
$ perldoc -l CGI
/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/CGI.pm
```

You can also find all the source at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/). Just looking at a single file in isolation generally isn't that fruitful, you'll want to look at all the files in the distribution as a coherent whole.

You'll probably want to familiarize yourself with the other things that `perldoc` can do:

> http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html